# Linq to entities multiple WHERE clause &&

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

In the code bdehind && syntax does not work, any ideas?

```
Entities ctx3 = new Entities();
var uniqueQuote = from quot in ctx3.Quotes.Include("aspnet_Users").Include("Enquiries")
  where quot.Enquiries.EnquiryId == selectedEnquiryId &&
     quot.aspnet_Users.UserId == currentUserId
  orderby quot.QuotePrice
  select quot;
```

Error   2   Delegate 'System.Func' does not take '1' arguments   C:\LocalGarageFinder\LocalGarageFinder\EnquiryDetail.aspx.cs    56  33  LocalGarageFinder

Comment: Delegate 'System.Func<LocalGarageFinder.Quotes,int,bool>' does not take '1' arguments C:\LocalGarageFinder\LocalGarageFinder\EnquiryDetail.aspx.cs 56 33 LocalGarageFinder

Comment: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type C:\LocalGarageFinder\LocalGarageFinder\EnquiryDetail.aspx.cs 56 33 LocalGarageFinder

Comment: It is solved, just had to instanciate currentUserId

Comment: you could post the correct syntax for others with the same problem. Tks

Answer (score 3):

The code as written is fine. If you are receiving some sort of error, please let us know.

Answer (score 3):

If EnquiryId or UserId is a Nullable type you will get the error. Use EnquiryId.Value == selectedEnquiryId or UserId.Value == currentUserId